# Implementing Instagram's Press Hold Thumbnail Image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am wondering how do we achieve the Instagram press and hold thumbnail feature?

When we press and hold on the Instagram UICollectionViewCell in Grid mode, there is a nice animation (Like a dialog opening) which will be dismissed once we release our hold.

Could anyone guide please? thank you

[image]

Comment: Which image?? Post image or user inage?

Comment: This is called "peek and pop", a 3D Touch feature: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/

Comment: I am not familiar with that particular application, but from the image it looks like you also want to present a menu where you can release your touch at a certain option, is that right? Or do you only wish to display a view?